# WP_Query order by not working properly due to category I believe

Tags: wp-query

I made a query where it should be ordered by the field external link then by price field the problem it seems that some of the post have multiple category can't seem to figure out why it is not going by order of external link fiend then by price field.

```
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'         => post,            
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'meta_query'     => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'price_clause' => array(
                'key' => 'price',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            ),
            'external_clause' => array(
                'key' => 'external_link',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            )
        ),

        'orderby'    => array(
            'external_clause' => 'DESC',
            'price_clause' => 'DESC',
        ),
        'tax_query' => array(array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'category',
                            'field'    => 'slug',
                            'terms'    => $category,
                        ),) 
    ) );
```

Comment: Does the sort work properly when testing without the tax query?

Comment: Also not working properly and it seems the problem is the meta query but can't figure out.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to fixed this the problem was type => 'numeric'

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type'         => post,            
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,

        'category_name'     => $category,


        'meta_query'     => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'price_clause' => array(
                'key' => 'price',
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            ),
            'external_clause' => array(
                'key' => 'external_link',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            )
        ),

        'orderby'    => array(
            'external_clause' => 'DESC',
            'price_clause' => 'DESC',
        ),

    ) );
```